# Custom modal Durandal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, durandal

I have been trying to work with the durandal framework and must say I'm very pleased. I'm using the Movie tutorial by http://stephenwalther.com/ and have made some changes. With help of the Ryan Keeters Youtube video's. I have accomplished editing movies with modals.

But I can't get it to work to add new movies via a modal.

I have created a add.html and add.js but when the link for creating a new movie is clicked and the modal shows it shows the page i'm at in the middle (like a loop when I click further).

THis is my binding on show.html:

```
<a data-bind="click: viewAddMovieModal">Add Movie</a>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
define(function (require) {
    var self = this;

    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        title: 'movies page',
        movies: ko.observableArray([])
    };
    //return vm;

   // self.moviesRepository = require("repositories/moviesRepository");
    self.router = require('durandal/plugins/router');
    self.system = require('durandal/system');
    self.app = require('durandal/app');
    self.movie = require('viewmodels/movie');
    self.addmovie = require('viewmodels/add');
    //self.Movies = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.viewMovieModal = function (movie, element) {
        self.app.showModal(movie).then(function (result) {
            if (result) {
                //self.app.showMessage(result.toString(), result.toString());
               vm.movies.remove(movie);
            }
        }).fail(function (result) {
            self.app.showMessage(result.toString(), "Something went wrong!");
        });
    };

    self.viewAddMovieModal = function (addmovie,element) {
      //  self.app.showModal(addmovie).then(function (result) {
         //   self.app.showMessage(result.toString(), result.toString());
      //  });
        self.app.showModal(null, element, addmovie);
    };

    init();

    function init() {
        vm.movies.push(new movie("Star wars", "Piet"));
        vm.movies.push(new movie("Harry Potter", "Jan"));
        vm.movies.push(new movie("Hangover", "Klaas"));
    }

    function activate() {
        self.system.log("I get in the activate function!");
    }

    return {
        activate: activate,
        movie: movie,
        addmovie:addmovie,
        vm:vm,
        viewMovieModal: viewMovieModal
    };
});
```

Comment: I got it fixed used the sample of custommodal that comes with durandal. But how do I pass multiple values on the closing statement of a modal?

Comment: Nevermind, made a JSON of my data... Or are there better ways? TO pass data in de app.modal.close()?

Comment: you can answer your own questions. And it benefits the community if you do so.